# Phaser 3: Call function from another class

Tags: typescript, class, phaser-framework

I have create updateCanvas() function in file a.ts:

```
export class loadscene extends Scene {
  textures1!: any
  textures2!: any
  textures3!: any
  constructor() {
    const key = 'loadscene'
    super(key)
  }
  updateCanvas(scene){
    switch (scene) {
      case 'canvastextures1':
        this.textures1.update()
        break
      case 'canvastextures2':
        this.textures2.update()
        break
      case 'canvastextures3':
        this.textures3.update()
        break
    }
  }
}
```

and in file b.ts I call to use this function but not working:

```
import { loadscene } from './load.scene'
export class BattleScene extends Scene {
  loadScene!: loadscene
...
      this.loadScene = new loadscene()
      this.loadScene.updateCanvas(tile.body.gameObject.texture.key)
```

I can use the function in the internal file but cannot call from another file. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I assume the problem is this line `this.loadScene = new loadscene()`.
When you initializing the property `this.loadScene`, you would have to **get** the created scene, not create a new one.
like this: `this.loadScene = this.scene.get('loadscene')`.

This should work *(if the compilier, throws an error, you should change the property from  `loadScene!: loadscene` to `loadScene!: any`, or may a cast could work like `this.loadScene = (this.scene.get('loadscene') as loadscene )`)*.

***P.s.:** I would change the parameter of the method `updateCanvas(scene)`, `scene` could be misunderstund since the parameter  is the ***key of the texture***.

And start the class names with uppercase. so `class LoadScene...` would be better.*

**Update:**
code in codepen shows, how I would use typescript to call functions from another scene https://codepen.io/akumagamo/pen/WNMQWJe
*In this codepen I'm changing texture from a different Scene*

[image: preview from CodePen]

**Here the relevant code *(without the texture part)*:**.

```ts
class FirstScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super('firstScene')
  }
  
  create(){
    console.log('Create Call in First Scene!')
    this.scene.start('secondScene')
  }
  
  testME(){
    console.info('TEST ME')
    return `called function "testME" from scene:${this.scene.key}`;
  }
  
}

class SecondScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  parentScene: any
  constructor() {
    super('secondScene')
    
  }
  
  create(){
    let text = this.add.text(10,10, '"Create" in Second Scene!', {'color':'#fff'});
    this.parentScene = this.scene.get('firstScene')
    let newLine = this.parentScene.testME();
    text.setText(text.text + '\n' + newLine);
  }
}
```

Comment: when I use `this.loadScene = this.scene.get('loadscene')`. It return:
`Type 'Scene' is missing the following properties from type 'loadscene': textures1, textures2, textures3, land1, and 5 more.ts(2740)`

Comment: Is the `Scene` class, the `Phaser.Scene` class? And how are the scenes loaded?

Comment: the scenes start with `this.scene.start()`

Comment: @CSNo.1 this is a typescript compile problem, the fastes solution is just to change `loadScene!: loadscene` to `loadScene: any` i think this should do the trick. But I'm not 100% sure since I write phaser apps, only in pure Javascript, to keep the workflow easy, with no need for compilation/transpilation. here so a mini demo on codepen https://codepen.io/akumagamo/pen/WNMQWJe

Comment: @CSNo.1 I update my anser and the code found in the linked CodePen, I think this should cover the basics, that your are looking for.